# How to "reduce" a probability distribution satisfying certain conditions

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I will try and explain the question I have in term of an example.

I am given some probability distribution $f$, in this case of $2$ variables $x$ and $p$, $f(x,p)$. For example, I can pick the Maxwell-Boltzmann (equilibrium) distribution in a harmonic potential:
$$
f(x,p) = A \exp \left[ - \beta \left( \frac{p^2}{2 m} + \frac{m}{2} \omega^2 x^2 \right) \right]
$$

For example, I am interested in the probability distribution when the energy $E = \frac{p^2}{2 m} + \frac{1}{2} m \omega^2 x^2$ is a constant. If we consider the case where $\frac{1}{2 m} = \frac{1}{2} m \omega^2$, we know all the equal-energy surfaces are circles in phase-space ($x$ vs $p$ plot). As there should be no preference in which value of $(x,p)$ is more probable, we can then deduce the resulting distribution would be uniform in $(x,p)$. I am not quite sure how to show this mathematically.

The more detailed version of my question is as follow:
I am given some probability distribution $f(x,y,z,p_x,p_y,p_z)$ and I am interested in the probability distribution when it satisfies $3$ conditions:

- $y p_z - z p_y = L_x$
- $z p_x - x p_z = L_y$
- $x p_y - y p_x = L_z$

($L_x$, $L_y$ and $L_z$ are constants that I can define)

Comment: This has nothing to do with the computer language Mathematica and should be moved.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Then vote to close

Comment: @belisarius He will not receive that [privilege](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) until he reaches 3000 points of *reputation.*

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I keep forgetting some nuisances. Thanks!